# Tkinter: How to distinguishing between long and short button click

Tags: python, tkinter

i am trying to achieve this behaviour: When user clicks the button for a shorter time  the program runs the first method, which lets say adds one. However, when user keeps the button pressed for a longer time the program runs the second method, which opens a dialog window. The only solution which came to my mind was using time thread.

The problem is that the program is acting really strangely.Sometimes (not always that's also weird) when the dialog pops up my computer kind of freezez(not exactly, the processes are running). I am able to move with my mouse but I am not able to click or write anything with my keyboard.

Here is a code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import threading
import os

class Dialog(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent, title = None):

        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.transient(parent)

        if title:
            self.title(title)

        self.parent = parent

        self.result = None
        body = Frame(self)
        self.initial_focus = self.body(body)
        body.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

        #self.buttonbox()

        self.grab_set()

        if not self.initial_focus:
            self.initial_focus = self

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.cancel)

        self.geometry("+%d+%d" % (parent.winfo_rootx()+50,
                                  parent.winfo_rooty()+50))

        self.initial_focus.focus_set()

        self.wait_window(self)

    #
    # construction hooks

    def body(self, master):
        # create dialog body.  return widget that should have
        # initial focus.  this method should be overridden

        pass

    def buttonbox(self):
        # add standard button box. override if you don't want the
        # standard buttons

        box = Frame(self)

        w = Button(box, text="OK", width=10, command=self.ok, default=ACTIVE)
        w.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        w = Button(box, text="Cancel", width=10, command=self.cancel)
        w.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.bind("<Return>", self.ok)
        self.bind("<Escape>", self.cancel)

        box.pack()

    #
    # standard button semantics

    def ok(self, event=None):

        if not self.validate():
            self.initial_focus.focus_set() # put focus back
            return

        self.withdraw()
        self.update_idletasks()

        self.apply()

        self.cancel()

    def cancel(self, event=None):

        # put focus back to the parent window
        self.parent.focus_set()
        self.destroy()

    #
    # command hooks

    def validate(self):

        return 1 # override

    def apply(self):

        pass # override

class MyDialog(Dialog):

    def body(self, master):
       master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
       self.e1 = Entry(master)
       self.e1.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan = 4)
       self.buttons = {}
       self.buttons['previous'] = Button(master,text =u'/')
       self.buttons['previous'].grid(column=0,row =1,columnspan = 2)

       self.buttons['next'] = Button(master,text =u'*')
       self.buttons['next'].grid(column=2,row =1,columnspan = 2)     

       self.buttons['minus'] = Button(master,text =u'-')
       self.buttons['minus'].grid(column=3,row =2)

       self.buttons['plus'] = Button(master,text =u'+')
       self.buttons['plus'].grid(column=3,row =3)

       self.buttons['enter'] = Button(master,text =u'Enter')
       self.buttons['enter'].grid(column=3,row =4,rowspan = 2)

       self.buttons['zero'] = Button(master,text =u'0')
       self.buttons['zero'].grid(column=0,row =5)

       self.buttons['del'] = Button(master,text =u'←')
       self.buttons['del'].grid(column=1,row =5)
       rows = range(4,1,-1)
       columns = range(0,3)

       i = 1
       for row in rows:
              for column in columns:
                     Button(master,text = i).grid(row= row,column = column)
                     i+=1
       return self.e1 # initial focus

def leftClick():
        print 'add one'

def longerClick(): #if the timer ends this will run
              d = MyDialog(master) #create dialog
              print 'longerClick'

def handleButtonPress(event):
              global t
              t = threading.Timer(0.8,longerClick) #setTimer
              t.start()
              print t
def handleButtonRelease(event): #here is a problem probably
              global t
              t.cancel()
              leftClick()

master = Tk()
t = None
master.geometry('{}x{}'.format(300, 300))
button = Button(master, text = 'Stlac')
button.pack()
button.bind('<ButtonPress-1>',handleButtonPress)
button.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',handleButtonRelease)
mainloop()
```

So when button is pressed I setup timer. When user releases the button before timer ends, the timer is canceled.When not, longerClick method runs. 
If you know where the problem is I would really aprecciate your help. Also if you know a better way how to detect longer button press that would also help me. I have read that it is possible in PYQT although I have to use Tkinter.